# What are tha main causes of slowness on Cisco PIX 515?

Tags: cisco, cisco-pix

A couple of Cisco PIX 515 work in standby mode. But the active PIX (or the otherone) never uses more then 40% of the available bandwidth on the outbound LAN interface (10Mbps).

Answer (score 3):

The PIX 515 can saturate at least one 100Mb connection, (almost) no matter what it's doing. Your problem is almost certainly with whatever it's plugged into. It could possibly be that the configuration has the bandwidth limited too.

Comment: In the Catalyst switch where the PIX interfaces are plugged, i don't see any error. I deleted from the PIX config any kind of logging. But there is no solution.  It is very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I just set up a new ASA with a new internet connection at a client site. I was getting dramatically slower speeds than expected. Nothing showed in any logs, etc.

Turned out that the port had auto negotiated to half duplex. I forced it to full duplex and everything began working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing HTTP inspection, which is on by default, you might want to consider testing with it disabled. I found I was getting max of about 3-5Mbps throughput on a 515E. Removing this from the default policy map let me saturate the link.